# Set Subview's Width Porportional to Superview's

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am trying to set a constraint that would look like this (subview in red superview in white):

[image]

How would I do this in interface builder (preferably) and if not possible then code, but what should I put as the width to make IB happy?

I have tried selecting the subview and superview, but it won't let me set constraints that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it entirely in IB. I don't know what you mean by "I have tried selecting the subview and superview, but it won't let me set constraints that way"; that, indeed, is *exactly* what you must do, and exactly what it *will* let you do — in short, that is precisely *how* you do a relationship of that sort.

I'll describe the whole thing in three stages. Start with your subview and draw out the initial constraints for top, left, and right:

[image]

Now select the view and its superview and use the popup at the bottom to set equal widths (of course when you are finished they will not be equal, but this is just to form the constraint itself):

[image]

Finally, fix all the constraint values by selecting each one in turn and editing its Constant in the attributes inspector. The values will all need to be 0, except for the widths relationship, of course; there, you'll enter the two values that you gave in your question:

[image]

You're now finished, but if you want the "misaligned" warnings to go away, choose Update All Frames to make the layout look the way it will at runtime. Or just run it and see what you've got!

**EDIT**: In a .xib, you won't be able to form the width = width constraint to the top-level view. To get around this, use an invisible intervening "container view" to act as a buffer between the top-level view and everything else. Pin the container view with zero values on all sides to the top-level view; now the container view will act as the container for everything else, and you'll be able to pin in terms of its width:

[image]

Comment: Attempting to do that all the check boxes (including equal widths) are unselectable. Does this have to do with the superview being the main view?

Comment: No it does not. It doesn't matter what two views these are, you can form a width-equality relationship between them. — Anyway, the screen shots prove you can do it.

Comment: Here is what I have: http://i.stack.imgur.com/alFxt.png. All the boxes are unselectable. The blue buttons are held in a UIView container the "subview" and the main view is the "superview".

Comment: Ah. It's because you're in a .xib, not a .storyboard. You will have to introduce an extra "container view" at top level, pinned to the main view on all sides, to give you something you can pin to.

Comment: Why does xcode not allow this in .xibs? Seems stupid. Is the only way to go programmatically then?

Comment: No, you'll be fine. Just use the "container view". I'll add a screen shot.

Comment: "Why does xcode not allow this in .xibs?" I'll have to give that some thought. You'd think there would be a reason for it. Perhaps it is obscurely related to the fact that only in a storyboard can we guarantee that this view will be a view controller's main view when it is instantiated... On the other hand, the workaround is trivial and harmless. However, you've got a simple and obvious use case, so why not file a bug report?

Comment: I plan on filing one. Maybe they can give an explanation of their reasoning. Until then I will use your view inside a view tactic.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar where I wanted a subview to be 25% of the superview.  The constraint looks like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewA
                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                        toItem:viewA.superview
                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                        multiplier:.5
                        constant:(CGFloat)-20];


[viewA.superview addConstraint:c];
```

As far as IB, you can just set a width constraint, then edit it and check the "Placeholder Remove at build time" box.   [Here's a link to my blog post that describes it better](http://saveme-dot-txt.blogspot.com/2014_03_01_archive.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you mind editing your solution so that it actually does what I asked though. That means probably a `0.5f` instead of `.25`, but what about the `20`?

Comment: okay, edited per your request - I think that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Without a container view, you can do it by adding trailing constraint with `Superview.CenterX`

```
subView.left = superView.left

subView.right = superView.CenterX + 20
```